# How to close the custom select option box

Tags: jquery, css, select

I've a custom select option box but I've a bug.

The bug is now, how do I close the custom select options when clicked outside.

In the default select options when clicked outside then the select options hide away and then again when clicked select box again the select options appear.

I want the same to appear to my custom select options.

```
<style type='text/css'>
        div.selectBox
        {
            position:relative;
            display:inline-block;
            cursor:default;
            text-align:left;
            line-height:30px;
            clear:both;
            color:#888;
        }
        span.selected
        {
            width:167px;
            text-indent:20px;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-right:none;
            border-top-left-radius:5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
            background:#f6f6f6;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        span.selectArrow
        {
            width:30px;
            border:1px solid #60abf8;
            border-top-right-radius:5px;
            border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
            text-align:center;
            font-size:20px;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -o-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            background:#4096ee;
        }

        span.selectArrow,span.selected
        {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
            height:30px;
            z-index:1;
        }

        div.selectOptions
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:28px;
            left:0;
            width:198px;
            border:1px solid #ccc;
            border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
            border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
            overflow:hidden;
            background:#f6f6f6;
            padding-top:2px;
            display:none;
        }

        span.selectOption
        {
            display:block;
            width:80%;
            line-height:20px;
            padding:5px 10%;
        }

        span.selectOption:hover
        {
            color:#f6f6f6;
            background:#4096ee; 
        }           
 </style>

  <div class='selectBox'>
        <span class='selected'></span>
        <span class='selectArrow'>&#9660</span>
        <div class="selectOptions" >
            <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Rob</span>
            <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Charles</span>
            <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Smith</span>
        </div>
    </div>


 <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type='text/javascript'><!--
        $(document).ready(function() {
            enableSelectBoxes();
        });

        function enableSelectBoxes(){
            $('div.selectBox').each(function(){
                $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').html());
                $(this).attr('value',$(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').attr('value'));

                $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function(){
                    if($(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none'){
                        $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','block');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display','none');
                    }
                });

                $(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function(){
                    $(this).parent().css('display','none');
                    $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value',$(this).attr('value'));
                    $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
                });
            });             
        }//-->
    </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pt9tryp2/4/)***

Use following

```
//My code

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".selectBox");

    if (!container.is(e.target)
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        $(".selectOptions").hide();
    }
});
```

For more refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it)

Comment: Thanks.
But I've another bug.that is When I have two select box and when I open one and at the same time when i open the second the first one is still opened.

so how canI close that when opening two select options at the same time?

Comment: Why not , let me try that too! :)

Comment: Thanks. I'm eagerly waiting for your reply.

Comment: @Mohamed , hey buddy , TAKE YOUR FIDDLE :) Enjoy :) http://jsfiddle.net/pt9tryp2/27/

Comment: @Mohamed and mohmmad , you made nice custom dropdown menu! :)

Comment: Thanks for your support for this custom select box.

Dude the answer for the second one works good in jsfiddle and codepen but its not working on my live site.

Comment: Then fix the issue with JS :) Its working on codepen,jsfiddle , so you must have made some mistake in your code for sure :) . I hope ,you will find issue in your code!

Comment: Thanks for your support to create a final cut custom select box. ;)

Comment: @Mohamed , welcome . and do it yourself , you get experience by falling !

Comment: Thats 100% true dude :)

Comment: I need an urgent help from you regarding this select option.

Comment: Waiting for your reply @jquery

Comment: Say it dude . Or post a question on stack overflow. And paste here link. I will answer for sure

Comment: Thanks Dude :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864478/how-to-create-a-custom-select-option/29864562#29864562

Comment: Can you do me a help in this select option?

Answer (score 2):

Use overlay when the select-box is open. When clicked on overlay, close the select-box. Here is the changes made.

CSS:

```
.selectBox {
    z-index: 101;
    /* should be 1 greater than overlay's z-index */
}
.overlay {
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: black;
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('.overlay').bind('click', function() {
    $('.selectBox .selectOptions').slideUp();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

When the selectBox is opened, show overlay, and hide the overlay when the selectBox is closed.

opacity of the overlay is shown for the purpose of understanding how it works. You can set opacity to zero.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(enableSelectBoxes);

function enableSelectBoxes() {
    $('div.selectBox').each(function() {
      $(this).children('span.selected').html($(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').html());
      $(this).attr('value', $(this).children('div.selectOptions').children('span.selectOption:first').attr('value'));

      $(this).children('span.selected,span.selectArrow').click(function() {
        if ($(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none') {
          $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display', 'block');
          $('.overlay').show();
        } else {
          $(this).parent().children('div.selectOptions').css('display', 'none');
        }
      });

      $(this).find('span.selectOption').click(function() {
        $('.selectBox .selectOptions').slideUp();
        $('.overlay').hide();
        $(this).parent().css('display', 'none');
        $(this).closest('div.selectBox').attr('value', $(this).attr('value'));
        $(this).parent().siblings('span.selected').html($(this).html());
      });
    });
  } //-->

$('.overlay').bind('click', function() {
  $('.selectBox .selectOptions').slideUp();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
div.selectBox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 30px;
  clear: both;
  color: #888;
  z-index: 101;
}
span.selected {
  width: 167px;
  text-indent: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span.selectArrow {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #60abf8;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: #4096ee;
}
span.selectArrow,
span.selected {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}
div.selectOptions {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  width: 198px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  padding-top: 2px;
  display: none;
}
span.selectOption {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10%;
}
span.selectOption:hover {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  background: #4096ee;
}
.overlay {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='selectBox'> <span class='selected'></span>
  <span class='selectArrow'>&#9660</span>

  <div class="selectOptions"> <span class="selectOption" value="Option 1">Rob</span>
    <span class="selectOption" value="Option 2">Charles</span>
    <span class="selectOption" value="Option 3">Smith</span>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4fej7gm/)

Comment: You are a lifesaver, dude. I applied this concept to vanilla JS and still worked as a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can add focus to the object when its clicked, then you can have an event listener that listens to when it loses focus (ie: when you click outside the box) and in that event handler, just close it.