# How to create a custom select option

Tags: jquery, html, select

How do I create a similar select option

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/139417/4167005d094aaeef54ae2b2a25b64dfb

This is my code.

```
<select name="" id="">
<option value="">Public</option>
<option value="">Private</option>
<option value="">Only Me</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap and button dropdowns
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Comment: Those are the normal dropdown not the select option.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this
[**Here**](http://www.bootply.com/b4NKREUPkN)

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  var selText = $(this).text();
  $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

Comment: No dear its not what I want.

Comment: What I need is In the select option you have the Icon plus the text but once you select it you get only the icon being displayed.

For more info you can check the screen shot.

Comment: In facebook , http://jsfiddle.net/stLuuh0b/21/  , there are links only inside Div with ul li, There is no real Drop down with <select> . I share a fiddle with you just to show facebook Dropdown.

Comment: Its there in fb, if you go to your profile older post and click the icon next your profile pic then it opens a dropdown for select to show your post as public, private or only me. Pls check it in fb in your profile post that you updated.

Comment: Hope you understood my question

Comment: Then you Should talk very clearly which section of facebook contains dropdown you want.Sorry but We are Not here to ask Asker 1000 questions to clarify issue. You should tell us Everything you want,how you want it. You should have told me about your expected dropdown very early, but you said it just now. Which clearly wastes my time

Comment: I'm sorry for it.
Can you help me on solving this issue?